# How do I solve this for theta?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

$$\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{\theta})}{\sin{\theta}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

How do I solve for $\theta$ here?

Comment: I am afraid that only numerical methods would do the job. Remember that there is no analytical solution to $x=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, only numerical methods would do the job.

Plot the function and locate approximate values of the solutions; for example, for $-10 \leq\theta \leq 10$, there solutions close to $-6,-4,1,2,7,8$.

Now, consider that you want to polish one of the roots; let us say the one close to $\theta_0=8$. Now, use Newton method which will update the solution according to 
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n-\frac{f(\theta_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ using $$f(\theta)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}   \cos (\theta )\right) \csc (\theta )-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$f'(\theta)=\frac{\pi}{2}   \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}   \cos (\theta )\right)-\cos
   \left(\frac{\pi}{2}  \cos (\theta )\right) \cot (\theta ) \csc (\theta )$$ The successive iterates will then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 8.00000 \\
 1 & 9.31385 \\
 2 & 8.52694 \\
 3 & 8.53536 \\
 4 & 8.53534
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Similarly, using $\theta_0=-6$, you would get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \theta_n \\
 0 & -6.00000 \\
 1 & -5.39490 \\
 2 & -5.39375
\end{array}
\right)$$  which is the solution for six significant figures.